# Is there a better way in c++ for one time execution of a set of code instead of using a static variable check

Tags: c++11

In many places i have code for one time initialization as below

```
int callback_method(void * userData)
{
   /* This piece of code should run one time only */
   static int init_flag = 0;
   if (0 == init_flag)
   {
     /* do initialization stuff here */
     init_flag = 1;
   }

   /* Do regular stuff here */

   return 0;
}
```

just now I started using c++11. Is there a better way to replace the one time code with c++11 lambda or std::once functionality or any thing else?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173384/how-to-make-sure-a-function-is-only-called-once    I think the second answer is good too.

Answer (score 3):

You can encapsulate your action to static function call or use something like *Immediately invoked function expression* with C++11 lambdas:

```
int action() { /*...*/ }
...
static int temp = action();
```

and

```
static auto temp = [](){ /*...*/ }();
```

respectively.

And yes, the most common solution is to use `std::call_once`, but sometimes it's a little bit overkill (you should use special flag with it, returning to initial question).

With C++11 standard all of these approaches are thread safe (variables will be initialized once and "atomically"), but you still must avoid races inside `action` if some shared resources used here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - `std::call_once`, see the docs on how to use this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once

Comment: Using std::call_once I see a similar implementaion, instead of static variable std::once_flag is used.                                            std::once_flag flag;
void testMethod2()
{
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}                                                                                                              int main()
{
        std::call_once(flag, testMethod2);
        std::call_once(flag, testMethod2);

        return 0;
}