# The meaning of "static char __ = []() -> char"

Tags: c++, lambda

I saw the code from several solutions from LeetCode's problems.

```
static char __ = []() -> char {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
return '\0'; }();
```

I understood that the following lines are for fast I/O.

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::cin.tie(NULL);
std::cout.tie(NULL);
```

However, I have no idea about

```
static char __ = []() -> char {
    // fast IO
return '\0'; }();
```

Can someone explain what is meaning of the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: There might be better or more in depth targets out there, that was just the first from google.

Comment: `__` identifier is reserved to the language implementation. If this variable definition is somewhere other than for example the standard library implementation, then it will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: reopened, I think there is more to be explained about this code than just "what is a lambda"

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use LeetCode as a place to learn C++. Or anything, really. The code there isn't necessarily good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code: `[]() -> char { return '\0'; }()`

is an *expression* which calls an unnamed [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11). In fact it contains some redundant elements and could have been written `[]{ return '\0'; }()`. Since empty argument list in lambdas can be omitted, and the return type can be deduced from the expression in the `return` statement.

The code is very similar to:

```
char qux() { return '\0'; }
char __ = qux();
```

except that there is no need for the identifier `qux` and therefore reduced chance of collision with some other identifier the program uses.

Naming the  variable `__` causes undefined behaviour since names containing double-underscore are reserved to the implementation, it'd be better for this code to use some valid identifier and that can perhaps be hidden via an unnamed namespace if there is a collision.

---

The purpose of this code is to execute the function body before `main()` runs.  It would be cleaner to have this code occur on the first line of `main()`, but perhaps the author was concerned that there might be some other code which also runs before `main()` and relies on these statements having executed.

However, this method does not really resolve the problem as if said other statements are in a different translation unit, there is no guarantee of `__`'s initialization occurring before the other unit's static initialization. See [static initialization order fiasco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822181/prevent-static-initialization-order-fiasco-c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now, I understood that the purpose of the code is to execute the function before main().

Answer (score 3):

`[]() -> char { ... }` is a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) taking no inputs and returning a `char`.

The `()` following the lambda is calling it, like any other function call.

The `char` value that the lambda is returning is being assigned to a static variable named `__`.

Since the variable is `static`, it will be initialized only once, so the lambda will be called only once.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41063745/65863) to [Is there a better way in c++ for one time execution of a set of code instead of using a static variable check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060998/)

Answer (score 2):

It's a C++ lambda, kind of an inline function (ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

It has no capture [] and no input argument () and returns char (-> char).

After define the lambda, then the code calls the lambda function. That is the last (); part. Otherwise it just defines the lambda, but not use it.